# R: multiple linear regression model and prediction model

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, linear-model

Starting from a linear `model1 = lm(temp~alt+sdist)` i need to develop a prediction model, where new data will come in hand  and predictions about `temp` will be made.

I have tried doing something like this:

`model2 = predict.lm(model1, newdata=newdataset)`

However, i am not sure this is the right way. What i would like to know here is, if this is the right way to go in order to make prediction about `temp`. Also i am a bit confused when it comes to the `newdataset`. Which values should be filled in etc.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`newdata` should contain a column for each of your predictive variables, `alt` and `sdist`. (Any variables except the one you're predicting.) For example:

```
newdata = data.frame(alt = newAltVector, sdist = newSdistVector)
predictions = predict.lm(model, newdata)
```

`predictions` will then contain a fitted y value for each new x. In the below, black dots represent training data, and the blue dots represent predicted values.

Whether that's the right way to predict `temp` depends on how well a linear model approximates the relationship between variables. Try this [intro](http://www.findnwrite.com/musings/evaluating-linear-regression-model-in-r/) to evaluating a linear model in R.

[image: Linear regression with toy data]

Comment: Well your answer helped a lot. Thanks for the link too. By the way how did you plotted the using `predictor` and `predicted` variables?

Comment: plot(x, y, xlab = "Predictor variable", ylab = "Predicted variable"); points(predictions, newdata$x, col = "blue")